# Mathematical formula for capturing amount of 1 inch rainfall on a tin roof messuring 4 ft x 8 ft?

Tags: watering, irrigation, wildlife

How many gallons of water can be captured from a tin roof measuring 4 ft x 8 ft, if you get a 1 inch rain?  Converted into gallons?

I want to build a water guzzler, but need to know the size of area of my tin roof guzzler in order to capture 60 gallons.

Comment: What is the pitch/slope of the roof? The answers below are for a dead flat 4x8, which would not drain well - though for low slopes, the difference is not particularly significant. Or; if the structure below is 4x8, the pitch does not matter since the projected area is 4x8, even though the roof is then larger in the sloped direction.

Comment: I think there are a few imperial units you haven't mentioned yet! :-)

Comment: Switch to metric, the rest will be obvious.

Comment: @Ecnerwal I reckon the size is going to be the horizontal size as it's easier to measure.  Anyway the effect of trigonometry is far smaller than the variability in rainfall

Comment: Is that US gallons or imperial gallons? (1 imperial gallon ≈ 1.2 US gallons)

Comment: As @Nobody said - in metric it is obvious - as a rough guide, for every 1mm of rain falling on a 1 square meter area you get 1 litre of water.    If we approximate 4ftx8ft to 2.9 square meters and 1 inch of rain to 25mm that means you would get 2.9 * 25 = 72 litres = approx 16 imperial gallons or 19 US gallons

Answer (score 5):

Thats 4 X 8 X 1/12 cubic feet or 2.67 cubic feet.

1 cubic feet is 7.4805194805 gallons

So the answer is almost 19.95 or 20 gallons

Answer (score 2):

The calculation for volume of a cube (and your roof+rainfall is a very squashed cube) is length x width x height. After converting length and width to inches you get 48 x 96 x 1 = 4608 cubic inches. Using [this calculator](https://www.unitconverters.net/volume/cubic-inches-to-gallons.htm), you get 19.945 gallons.

Your 4'x8' roof can capture 3" of rain in a 60 gallon system. A 12' x 8' roof would capture 1" of rain in that same system.

Comment: Or ; 231 cu in. / gallon.

Answer (score 0):

First you compute the roof area, then you multiply by the amount of rain to have the volume of rain, and finally you convert to gallons:

```
        in          in                3             gallon
(4ft·4×3--)·(8ft·4×3--)·1in = 512×9 in = 4608 c_in -------- = 19.95 gallon
        ft          ft                             231 c_in

 side 1       side 2   rain
 ------- area -------
```

May I respectfully ask "Why 231?"?